# Обьединение массивов с обьединением одинаковых элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, for, foreach

у меня есть два массива
`let first = ['hi','bye','hello'] let second = ['one','hi','bye']`  . Теперь мне нужно обьединить их в один массив в котором будут элементы обоих массивов, но если будут одинаковые, то они будут обьединяться в один элемент, в итоге мы получим что-то типа `third = ['hi','bye','hello','one']` (последовательность элементов не имеет значения)
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `[...new Set(first.concat(second))]`

Answer (score 1):

1. Присоединяем к массиву `first` массив `second` при помощи [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat);
2. Полученный массив избавляем от дубликатов — сначала преобразовываем его в `Set`, затем полученный `Set` обратно в массив при помощи `[... new Set(...)]`. Многоточие здесь распаковывает итерируемый объект, коим является `Set` — немного подробнее об этом можно прочесть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928416/how-does-new-setarray-works-in-javascript).

В общей сложности получим нечто такое:

```js
let first = ['hi','bye','hello']
let second = ['one','hi','bye']
console.log([...new Set(first.concat(second))]);
```

Comment: Благодарствую за развернутый ответ